# Keep QTreeView sorted

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I have a `QTreeView` with 3 columns. After I remove an element from the tree model I use the following to try to keep it sorted:

```
sort(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
```

I expected that would re-sort the whole tree using column `0` as the sorting key. However it's behaving weird, nodes appear repeated, etc. after that sort is executed. What's wrong?

What's the way to keep it sorted all the time?

Comment: You should probably take a look at [sortByColumn](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#sortByColumn).  There is also a property to hold whether or not should the treeview be always sorted

Comment: Yes, I'm also using:   ui->treeView->sortByColumn(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);

Comment: But, what's that property?

Comment: [sortingEnabled](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#sortingEnabled-prop)

Comment: I have that set but it's not autosorting... should I do something from my model?

Comment: What is the model class in use?